# Windows store app WInRT XAML C# - How to get navigated page textbox value

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

Windows store app WInRT XAML C# - How to get navigated page textbox value.here is my all code...................................................

1.MainPage.xaml

```
    <Button Content="Navigate" Name="nav" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="826,198,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="nav_Click"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="402,201,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="27" Width="155"/>
    <Frame Name="framee"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="440" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="600" Margin="402,238,0,0"/>
    <Button Content="Get" Name="get" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1062,193,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="get_Click"/>
```

2.InfoPage.xaml

```
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Name="Name" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,6,0,0" Width="348"/>
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Name="Address" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,43,0,0" Width="348"/>
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Name="Phone" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,80,0,0" Width="348"/>
```

MainPage.cs

```
 private void nav_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        framee.Navigate(typeof(InfoPage));
    }

    private void get_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      here textbox name are not showing
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple enough question. Try this:

### MainPage.xaml

```
<TextBox x:Name="MyTextBox" Text="Hello" />
<Button Click="Button_Click" />
```

### MainPage.xaml.cs

```
void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Frame.Navigate(typeof(InfoPage), MyTextBox.Text);
}
```

### InfoPage.xaml

```
<TextBlock x:Name="MyTextBlock" />
```

### InfoPage.xaml.cs

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    MyTextBlock.Text = e.Parameter?.ToString();
}
```

That will do it.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve what you're asking for.  If you are using an MVVM pattern (which I personally highly recommend) then you simply need to bind the TextBox.Text to a field in the ViewModel and do the same to the same ViewModel in the MainPage... (and this could be discussed deeper so let me know if this is what you're doing.)  If you're not using the MVVM pattern then you probably have no idea what I'm talking about so let's look at other options.

Another possible solution is to Interface the new pages requiring them all to have the same interface that in turns exposes the TextBox.Text property or a TextBox with the same name or however you decide.  This is a big deeper as it may rely on other internal features such as Dependency Injection and or Controllers depending on how you're setup.

If you still have no idea what I'm talking about then I'm going to assume you're semi new at all of this and suggest you simply look for the TextBox via different approaches.  It would be much easier to answer the question directly if you provided the full code and XAML for both pages at least.

Comment: MainPage.Xml : 
<Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="54" Margin="92,522,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="114"/>

Comment: MainPage : 

 <ScrollViewer Margin="330,20,0,0" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
            <Frame Name="FormFillProfileFrame"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="auto"/>

        </ScrollViewer>

Comment: please send me your email..am new here face problem to comment here

Comment: @Aizaz Ahmad you could edit your question by adding your code in it, in this way we can help you better, Thank you!

Comment: @Cherry Bu i Edited my question...it was very taff to edit .. (^-^)

Comment: Apologies, my email is michael.puckett.ii@outlook.com